# Compass Sprite returning "File to import not found or unreadable"

Tags: sprite, compass

So, I've just started using the Compass Framework, and now wish to start using its native spriting feature. In doing so, I've added the following to the top of my scss file:

```
@import 'compass/utilities';
@import "*.png";
@include all-img-sprites;
```

After compiling, I get the following error:

```
error path/to/my/project/css/scss/front.scss (Line 4: File to import not found or unreadable: *.png.

Load paths:
Compass::SpriteImporter
path/to/my/project/css/scss
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets)
Compilation failed in 1 files.
[Finished in 1.7s]
```

I've looked around for a solution to this, but to my surprise, even though there's multiple threads on it - I can't seem to find anything relevant.

I've tried renaming the folders thinking that the "img" folders might be keyworded or something, but to no avail. Below you'll find my **config.rb**.

```
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = ""

# Configure sass path
sass_path=  "path\\to\\my\\project\\css\\scss"

# Folder locations
sass_dir        = "css/scss"
css_dir         = "css" 
images_dir      = "img" 
fonts_dir       = "fonts"
javascripts_dir = "js"
sprite_load_path = "img"

# Disable debugging comments that display the original location of your          selectors
line_comments = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, there we go! After a bit more fiddling about.
The issue was the path. Removing the sprite_load_path from the `config.rb` file, and changing the above to:

```
@import "raw/*.png";
@include all-raw-sprites;
```

Works fine. Note that the img folder is still set in the config.rb.